# Culture of thread for method render of LocalReport

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I'm using a localreport object into an asp.net application.
This report is fed by an array of object. So on the render of the report, some properties of the classe are called.

```
Class ClassForReport
{
  string Date
  {
    get{return _aDate.ToshortDateString();}
  }
}
```

Now the code for rendering and the problem:

```
//first of all, I change de culture for taking in account the choice of the user
CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(isoLanguageName_);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci; 
//Here, my culture is now: FR-be

MyLocalReport.render(...) // in this method, the property Date above is called. And when debugging I see that the culture is EN !!!

...
//and here, my culture is still Fr-be
```

So it seems that when the method render is called, it launch a thread and take the culture of the server and not the culture of the process.

The only workarround I see is changing my report to contains a date and then giving a parameter of culture and formating all my date in all my reports to the given culture...

So I realy hope there is a way to tell the report to take the curent culture of the asp thread and not taking some other culture comming from nowhere.

thx in advance

Answer (score 8):

In "`.rdlc`" **Designer** on your ReportFile, set on the Report in **Language** property "`=User!Language`".

```
<Report>
  ... 
  <Language>=User!Language</Language>
  ...
</Report>
```

then your `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE");`
will work on the values in `report.Render(...);` like dates,etc.

Cheers.

Comment: This helped a lot!