# Using Custom Culture with ReportViewer returns a CultureNotFoundException

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer, cultureinfo

My web site uses custom cultures that are created like this:

```
var cib = new CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder("en-gb-xxxx", CultureAndRegionModifiers.None);
cib.LoadDataFromCultureInfo(new CultureInfo("en-gb"));
cib.LoadDataFromRegionInfo(new RegionInfo("en"));
cib.Register();
```

And that are used like this:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-gb-xxxx");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-gb-xxxx");
```

It is all working fine up to the point I want to render a report with the ReportViewer control. The report text renders ok but the images fail and I get the following error:

*System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException: Culture is not supported. Parameter name: culture 4096 (0x1000) is an invalid culture identifier*

After a lot a googling I found a lot of other people asking the same question, unfortunately always left unanswered. [This article](http://codinginthetrenches.com/2014/04/03/net-custom-cultures-and-sqlserver-reporting-services/) describes the problem very clearly but does not offer any solution.

Is there anyone who could offer if not a fix, a workaround?

Answer (score 3):

As no answer came up I had to hack my way through:

First I created a `CustomReportViewer`, inheriting from the native `Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer` overriding the `OnPreRender` method. It checks the culture of the logged user (saved in Session) and roll back to the parent culture if any.

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    var culture = new CultureInfo(HttpContext.Current.Session["UserCulture"]);
    if (culture.CompareInfo.LCID != culture.LCID){
        var baseCulture = new CultureInfo(culture.CompareInfo.LCID);
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = baseCulture;
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = baseCulture;
    }
    base.OnPreRender(e);
}
```

Then I changed the object in the aspx page:

```
<web:CustomReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" AsyncRendering="false" SizeToReportContent="true" ProcessingMode="Remote">
```

Et voilà

I won't accept this answer hoping someone can come up with something... cleaner

Comment: We had the exact same issue and came to a similar solution. We did the following things differently: (1) We only "fixed" the CurrentCulture. Having CurrentUICulture point to a user-defined culture seems to work fine. Note: We only use LocalReport.Render to create a PDF, not the full ReportViewer control, so that might make a difference. (2) We create the "base" culture by cutting the "-xxxx" suffix from CurrentCulture.ToString(). Your CompareInfo.LCID solution looks intriguing, but I don't understand *why* it works correctly, which is why I didn't use it.

Comment: (3) We revert the culture back to its original value after calling LocalReport.Render.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution of the above issue:

**Issue:**

In Report Viewer on export Culture is not supported. Parameter name: culture 4096 (0x1000) is an invalid culture identifier.

**Solution::**

1.) Add below directive on the top

```
<% @Import Namespace="System.Globalization" %> 
<% @Import Namespace="System.Threading" %>
```

Or

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Globalization;
```

2.) Add event as below:

```
protected void FPReportViewer_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
}
```

3.) Update Reportviewer html tag as below:

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer runat="server" ID="FPReportViewer" OnPreRender="FPReportViewer_PreRender" AsyncRendering="false" width="100%"  SizeToReportContent="True"> </rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

may this code help you.

Thanks Alot!

Comment: Not too sure how this answer is different than mine, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Try this before send to SSRS

```
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture =
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture =
                CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
```

for example:

```
 [SessionExpire]
        public ActionResult ReportProduct(string ExpenseCenter)
        {                   
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture =
                    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture =
                        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");

            ReportViewer reportViewer = new ReportViewer();
            reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
            reportViewer.SizeToReportContent = true;
            reportViewer.AsyncRendering = false;

            reportViewer.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.FullPage;
            reportViewer.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
            reportViewer.Height = Unit.Percentage(100);

            var serverReport = reportViewer.ServerReport;

            serverReport.ReportPath = "/Reports/ReportPrice";
            serverReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://ssrs-server:94/ReportServer_MSSQLSERVER2016/");
            serverReport.SetParameters(GetParametersServer());
            serverReport.Refresh();

            ViewBag.ReportViewer = reportViewer;

            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

And then there is this answer when you are  rendering/exporting the rdlc report directly to other formats without using ReportViewer: [Culture of thread for method render of LocalReport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164548/culture-of-thread-for-method-render-of-localreport)