# getting commas instead of decimal Dynamic CommonReport

Tags: c#, webforms, reporting

I am creating a commonreport but I am getting decimal values with commas instead of dot. I tried to change the culture value as below and got same commas in my pdf

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

This is my code:

```
 ReportGenerator gen = new ReportGenerator(tbl, dt);
    
    ReportDataSource ds = new ReportDataSource(tbl, dt);
    LocalReport report=new LocalReport();
Tuple<System.IO.Stream, float> res = gen.GeneraReport(compName, prm, abbr, font);
    report.LoadReportDefinition(res.Item1);
    
    Byte[] mybytes = report.Render("PDF"); //for exporting to PDF
    using (FileStream fs = File.Create(fn))
    {
        fs.Write(mybytes, 0, mybytes.Length);
    }

    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = false;
    Response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    Response.AddHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "Application/x-pdf");
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ".pdf");
    Response.WriteFile(fn);
    Response.End();
```

I expect it as

```
ColumnName
1000.0
```

Actual output in pdf is

```
ColumnName
1000,0
```

My Main question being, how to change the culture of commonreport to Indian culture pertaining the current coding.
thanks in advance

Comment: See if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5965748/579895) helps

Comment: Hi I tried it. It didn't work. Any other links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the culture of the report by changing

```
 LoadReportDefinition
```

property and it worked.
Now I am getting decimals instead of commas in PDF
I had to place a breakpoint at "string content" and read its contents to find out what culture the report is using

```
 Tuple<System.IO.Stream, float> res = gen.GeneraReport(compName, prm, abbr, font);
    string content = new StreamReader(res.Item1, Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd();
    content = content.Replace("<Language>it-IT</Language>", "<Language>en-IN</Language>");

    //report.LoadReportDefinition(res.Item1);
    report.LoadReportDefinition(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content)));
```

Thanks everyone who helped me
regards